# Is the direct sum of Hilbert spaces a 'topological subspace' of the direct product equipped with the product topology?

Tags: general-topology, hilbert-spaces, direct-sum, direct-product

I am a bit confused about the topological relation between the direct sum and direct product of separable (possibly infinite dimensional) Hilbert spaces $\{H_n\}$.

In order to avoid complications further, suppose that $n$ is a countable index.

Then, we can first think of the 'direct product' of $\{H_n\}$, denoted as
\begin{equation}
\prod_{n=1}^\infty H_n
\end{equation}
equipped with the product topology.

And the 'orthogonal' direct sum of $\{H_n\}$ is a vector subspace of $\prod_{n=1}^\infty H_n$ defined by
\begin{equation}
\bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty  H_n :=\Bigl\{ (x_n) \in \prod_{n=1}^\infty H_n \mid \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lVert x_n \rVert^2 < \infty \Bigr\},
\end{equation}
which is a Hilbert space itself.

However, I am not sure whether $\bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty  H_n$ is a 'topological subspace' of $\prod_{n=1}^\infty H_n$. That is, I wonder if
\begin{equation}
\text{the topology of }\bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty  H_n\text{ inherited from }\prod_{n=1}^\infty H_n
\end{equation}
is equal to the Hilbert space topology of $\bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty  H_n$.

I think the answer is yes, but cannot figure out how to start a rigorous proof.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio: That should be an answer.

Comment: I think it has been deleted??